# SSRS report template Code

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to write the VBA code within the SSRS report templates and I have different conditions that map to a the same outcome. The example is when someone selectes an option "Employee picked" or "Single picked" or "Emp Picked"

`Public Function ChangeCov(ByVal s As String) As String 
   s= s.Trim()
If s.ToUpper = "Picked".ToUpper Or s.ToUpper ="Single".ToUpper
    Return "S"
Else : Return s
End If
End function`

is there a way like in SQL putting a wildcard in?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use custom code; you can just use a normal SSRS expression:

Sample data:

[image]

Simple table:

[image]

The expression here is:

```
=IIf(UCase(Fields!s.Value) like "*PICKED*", "S", Fields!s.Value)
```

Note that the wildcard character is `*`.

This gives what I believe are the required results:

[image]

If you want to use the expression in multiple places in the report, add it as a Calculated Field in the DataSet.

If the values are all well-known, you could always just explicitly list them all in the expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!s.Value = "Employee picked"
        or Fields!s.Value = "Single picked"
        or Fields!s.Value = "Emp Picked"
    , "S"
    , Fields!s.Value)
```

Finally, if you want to do this in the Custom Code, you could look at using the [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function, but I think if you can handle this in the report itself this is easier to use and maintain.

Comment: Ok thanks @Ian Preston I will have a go and then I will let you know how it goes

Comment: I have tried to use the wildcard expression but for what I was doing there was too many variation of categories which could be selected, but thanks all the same :)